# Ajax email and password validation keep returning false result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have an issue with ajax email and password validation. I know nothing wrong with the controller and model because when I remove `e.preventDefault();` it returning a correct result. why the ajax code always returning false ?  is that because I am using MD5 type for password or this thing  `data: "email=" + email + "&" + "password=" + password,` is incorrect.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();        //<---- stop submiting the forms
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>KulinerControl/otentikasi",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "email=" + email + "&" + "password=" + password,                   
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.valid) {
                    $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                    // $("#myform").submit();    //<---- submit the forms
                } else {
                    $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller

```
function otentikasi() {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $exists = $this->KulinerModel->otentikasi($email, $password);

    if($exists) {
        $msg = array(
            'valid' => true,
            'msg'   => 'correct'
        );
    } else {
        $msg = array(
            'valid' => false,
            'msg'   => 'error !'
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

View

```
<?php echo form_open('KulinerControl/otentikasi', 'id="myform"'); ?>
<span id="msg"> </span> 
    <label for="email>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" required> 
    <label for="password"  >password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" required> 
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

**SOLVED**

i am using `$("#formlogin").serialize()`

Comment: You could try `data: $("#myform").serialize()`

Comment: @ccKep absolutely, thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Send data in object format`{}`.And use `JSON.parse()` to parse your json response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();        //<---- stop submiting the forms
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('KulinerControl/otentikasi');?>",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {email:email,password:password},                   
        success: function(response){
            var data = JSON.parse(response)//or data = eval(response);
            if(data.valid){
                $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                // $("#myform").submit();    //<---- submit the forms
            }else{
                $('#msg').html(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

And don;t forget to load url helper in controller.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

OR load helper in `application/config/autoload.php`

Your view must be like this..

```
<?php echo form_open('', array('id'=>'myform')); ?>
<span id="msg"> </span> 
    <label for="email>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required> 
    <label for="password"  >password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required> 
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @highcal did you try above answer.

Comment: also load form helper.

Answer (score 0):

In **js** you have fetch value through **`$('#email').val();`** and **`$('#password').val();`** But you have not specify the **id attribute** of both input field. So **add id attribute** in both input as require.

To get more idea about **jquery selector** visit **http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp**

**Try this**

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open('KulinerControl/otentikasi', 'id="myform"'); ?>
<span id="msg"> </span> 
    <label for="email>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required> 
    <label for="password"  >password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required> 
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**js**

```
**$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        //<---- stop submiting the forms
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>KulinerControl/otentikasi",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "email=" + email + "&" + "password=" + password,                   
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.valid) {
                    $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                    // $("#myform").submit();    //<---- submit the forms
                } else {
                    $('#msg').html(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});**
```

**Controller**

```
function otentikasi() {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $exists = $this->KulinerModel->otentikasi($email, $password);

    if($exists) {
        $msg = array(
            'valid' => true,
            'msg'   => 'correct'
        );
    } else {
        $msg = array(
            'valid' => false,
            'msg'   => 'error !'
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

Comment: welcome. If above solution is working please right mark it so other can get idea.